# How to pass values when using right click open link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using onclick inside the 'a' tag and when I click on it, it goes to another page and I got the values perfectly. But when I use Right click and Open in new tab I reached in that page but values do not come as I am using onclick. Now how can I get the values when I open new tab? Please share your ideas. 
I have added my code below.

```
<a id="+scheme_code+" href='/home/index_latest?' onclick='setvalue(this.id)'>scheme name</a>
```

Comment: if you wish to pass the values, then you need to include them in the request you send, either as a GET or a POST, modifying some values on this page and expecting them to appear on a different page won't work. Try to use Forms, and then post the values.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your onclick function

```
var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/'+id, '_blank');
if (win) {
//Browser has allowed it to be opened
win.focus();
} else {
//Browser has blocked it
alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onmousedown`:

```
<a id="+scheme_code+" href='/home/index_latest?' onmousedown='setvalue(this.id)'>scheme name</a>
```

Comment: onmousedown open this in same window. Does not show "open link in new tab"

Comment: @PriyankDey onclick is fired only with left click but onmousedown is fired with both left or right click. Isn't this what you asked for?